# NDSolve for Coupled ODE with parameters

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics

Here I solved sys1 using NDSolve for the parameter m. I want to solve sys2 using NDSolve. But in sys2 I have a term consisting of the derivative of the solution obtained from sys1. I am stuck on how to write that term in sys2 so that I can plot the solution of sys2 for two values the parameter m?

```
    zeta = 2.0;
    (*m=5.0;*)
    a = 0.5;
    b = 2.0;
    x = 0.4;
    t = 0.2;
    Q0 = 1.0;
    alp = 0.5;
    alpha = 0.5;
    beta = 1.0;
    k = 0.5;
    F = Q0*Exp[-alp*t];
    h = 1.0 - (a*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]*Cos[Pi*(x - t)]);
    sys1 = {s''[y] == (m/alpha)*Sinh[alpha*s[y]]};
    iv1 = {s'[0] == 0, s[h] == 1};
    sol1[m_] := NDSolve[Join[sys1, iv1], s, {y, 0, h}];
    sys2 = {p''''[y] - (1/k)*p''[y] + beta*m*m*s[m]'[y] == 0};
    iv2 = {p[0] == 0, p''[0] == 0, p[h] == F, p'[h] == 0};
    sol2[m_] := NDSolve[Join[sys2, iv2], p, 8 {y, 0, h}];
    P1 = Evaluate[Table[p'[y] /. sol2[m], {m = 5}]];
    P2 = Evaluate[Table[p'[y] /. sol2[m], {m = 10}]];
    Plot[{P1, P2}, {y, 0, h}, PlotRange -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {y, u},
      Frame -> False, PlotStyle -> {{DotDashed, Red}, {Line, Blue}}, 
     PlotLegends -> Placed[{"m = 5  ", "m = 10 "}, Center]]
```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, I could not make it use `ParametricNDSolveValue` on both ode's. So this is a workaround

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
zeta=2.0;
(*m=5.0;*)
a=0.5;
b=2.0;
x=0.4;
t=0.2;
Q0=1.0;
alp=0.5;
alpha=0.5;
beta=1.0;
k=0.5;
F=Q0*Exp[-alp*t];
h=1.0-(a*Cos[Pi*(x-t)]*Cos[Pi*(x-t)]);
sys1=s''[y]==(m/alpha)*Sinh[alpha*s[y]]
iv1={s'[0]==0,s[h]==1}
sol1=ParametricNDSolveValue[{sys1,iv1},{s,s'},{y,0,h},{m}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
m0=5;
sys2=p''''[y]-(1/k)*p''[y]+beta*m0*m0*sol1[m0][[2]][y]==0;
iv2={p[0]==0,p''[0]==0,p[h]==F,p'[h]==0};
sol2At5=NDSolveValue[{sys2,iv2},{p,p'},{y,0,h}];

m0=10;
sys2=p''''[y]-(1/k)*p''[y]+beta*m0*m0*sol1[m0][[2]][y]==0;
sol2At10=NDSolveValue[{sys2,iv2},{p,p'},{y,0,h}] ;
```

This is the function solution:

```
Plot[{sol2At5[[1]][y], sol2At10[[1]][y]}, {y, 0, h}, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {y, u}, Frame -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> {{DotDashed, Red}, {Line, Blue}}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"m = 5  ", "m = 10 "}, Center]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And this is the derivative solution

```
Plot[{sol2At5[[2]][y], sol2At10[[2]][y]}, {y, 0, h}, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {y, u}, Frame -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> {{DotDashed, Red}, {Line, Blue}}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"m = 5  ", "m = 10 "}, Center]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note, you can also solve for derivative and not just the function.
For some reason, NDSolve did not like this

```
sys2 = p''''[y] - (1/k)*p''[y] + beta*m*m*sol1[m][[2]][y] == 0;
iv2 = {p[0] == 0, p''[0] == 0, p[h] == F, p'[h] == 0};
sol2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{sys2, iv2}, {p, p'}, {y, 0, h}, {m}]
```

That is why I had to solve it twice for each `m`

Comment: In the first you use m .. but why m0 in the second? Also, I have to use the derivative of sol1 in sol2. And what does [[2]] mean while solving sys2?

Comment: @Dr.B.Mallick It does not matter what letter is used in the second case. I used `m0` to avoid problem when you run the code again on the first code. This way `m` stays free variable. That is all. And yes [[2]] means the derivative solution. You can solve for both the function and its derivative at same time. Then [[1]] picks the function solution and [[2]] picks the derivative solution. There is no need to solve for the function and then do derivative on it later on. Let NDSolve do it for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2):

`ParametricNDSolveValue` can be used as follows to obtain a solution.  With the constants defined as in the question and

```
sys1 = {s''[y] == (m/alpha)*Sinh[alpha*s[y]]};
iv1 = {s'[0] == 0, s[h] == 1};
sys2 = {p''''[y] - (1/k)*p''[y] + beta*m*m*s'[y] == 0};
iv2 = {p[0] == 0, p''[0] == 0, p[h] == F, p'[h] == 0};

sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{sys1, iv1, sys2, iv2}, {s[y], p[y]}, {y, 0, h}, {m}];
```

The solution for `m = 5` is

```
sol[5];
Plot[%, {y, 0, h}, AxesLabel -> {y, "s,p"}, LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

and similarly for other values of `m`.